# Fan sighs/pulses/works for a second in idle every minute

Tags: windows, dell-inspiron

Win10, upgraded to win11--same thing.

A Dell G7 laptop.

- After a restart.
- Doing nothing. CPU idle 99%.
- Temperature of cpu, gpu, and harddrives <50c.

The fan starts working for a second, randomly every minute or so.

It doesn't happen on linux mint, although it was just a brief check.

For some periods of time (a few hours), it can remain quiet, but mostly it doesn't.

I tried to track an offending app with procmon and the task manager, but I got nothing. Could be some pulse that is less than 1sec to register. Still, I don't see any justification for running the fan for that.

Unfortunately, Dell doesn't offer any fan control. It has a power management app, which I set to quiet, but it only controls the speed and noise of the fan when the pulse happens.

SpeedFan seems obsolete and doesn't read the tempreture correctly. HWiNFO did nothing after I set the fan to 0RPM if <60c.

This is obviously Dell's fault of poor management, but maybe there's something that can be done on Windows' side. At least until I replace this laptop:

https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-G7-7590-fan-sighs-for-a-second-randomly/m-p/8277545/thread-id/151767

---

Dell didn't approve a full refund. Not sure what to do.

This is the hardware monitor just before that fan spikes (currently, every half a minute). Do you see any reason for it:

[image: hardware monitor]

I also wrote a script (psmon.py) to log the change in the top processes:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V2dy9HJXwXKRvYIWH4tXrD9JS8keOH5A/view

I killed most of the background processes, and just waited until the fan spikes. Also, for a more accurate reading, I reduced the number of cores in the bios to one.
This is a typical output:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V44UUFKIdfO7OVy4clf60B5eh-BAnvdk/view

There's usually noise from win process: svchost.exe, dwm.exe, explorer.exe, services.exe. However, there's nothing unusual before the fan spikes compared to the period between spikes.

---

After I hibernate and immediately turn it on, the fan is quiet. Maybe if the laptop is on more than a day, then the bios tells it to start annoying the user with the fan?

---

Coming to think of it, it's the same noise, same pulse when I do restart. Maybe there's a disconnection every minute, and this is the noise of the fan initializing?

---

Dell support asked me to take a video of the laptop. I have only my Logitech webcam. Its app takes 10% cpu, and the fan works in a low hum and doesn't pulse.

Which made me realize again that in some of the fan pulses, it starts in mid range and lowers into a barely noticebale hum before shutting down. In these cases (when it's not just turns on and off in a span of 1sec), maybe it's not unreasoble for it to work, but it should start gradually--a design flaw?

Maybe if the fan would never shut off but always spins in a low hum (or gradually go high and low) it would be unnoticiable?

---

I wrote a script (busy.py) that engages the gpu (cpu alone isn't enough). The fan works constantly on a low speed (and doesn't pulse).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VcTyrTs92jAP7ti1KZ3wJmtElAy0q6gS/view

Comment: Are you describing an actual problem, or just a preference? Fans spin based on the needs of the system, and it's normal for them to spin briefly and stop. The fan spinning and then not spinning is normal. So please describe an actual problem, if you have one. If this is your only issue: there's no problem here.

Comment: Yes, this is a severe noise issue for me, such that I filed for a full refund, and I'd like to get a new laptop--different brand, of course. In the settings that I described, there's no reason whatsoever for the fan to operate. Moreover, operating for 1sec has absolutely zero effectiveness of cooling down the system even if it was needed.

Comment: This actually reminds me of how Dell systems seem to always pulse fans on _power-on,_ so maybe it happens whenever the embedded controller is resetting, and your laptop's EC keeps resetting? (Wild ass guess)

Comment: Yeah, one of my suspicions. Not sure how to verify it, though.

Comment: And then I thought that maybe it's not even a malfuction: something turns it on, even mildly, every minute, and the fun pulses when turning on. Anyway, my current solution seems reasonable.